# Cannot connect to MySQL server database in program [VB]

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Firstly, as far as I know sharing the username/password should NOT be done as I'm attempting to make a user register/login program. My server is remote, so I connect to it with an IP address. I have been trying for a very long time but I always run into errors.

Even when providing the MySQL Username and password, it fails entirely.

Some stuff I've tried:

```
Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=(ip);port=22;username=root;password=(pwd);database=(db)")

Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=(ip);port=3306;username=root;password=(pwd);database=(db)")

Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=(ip);port=22;username=root;password=(pwd);database=(db)")
```

And then I realised another thing about my server, I require the SSH option when connecting so I tried this. However I still encounter the same errors on opening the MySQLConnection (portFwld.Start & Client.Connect is successful)

```
    Dim ConnectionInfo = New PasswordConnectionInfo("(IP)", "root", "(PWD)")
    Dim ConString = New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
    ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7)
    Dim client = New SshClient(ConnectionInfo)
    client.Connect()
    Dim portFwld = New ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", Convert.ToUInt32("3306"), "(IP)", Convert.ToUInt32("22"))
    client.AddForwardedPort(portFwld)
    portFwld.Start()

    ConString.Server = "(IP)"
    ConString.Port = "22"
    ConString.UserID = "root"
    ConString.Password = "(PWD)"
    ConString.Database = "(DB)"
    Dim Connection = New MySqlConnection(ConString.ToString)
    Connection.Open()
```

The errors I encountered were mostly these:

> {"Reading from the stream has failed."}

and:

> {"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."}

I literally have no idea why nothing is working whatsoever. I've searched and searched and I cannot find the solution. Also a reminder; I'm pretty sure I *don't* want the password revealed so blatantly in a string, let alone revealed at all.

Please be considerate as I'm completely new to this and just want to setup a community program just like any other program/site (like accounts here on Stackoverflow).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to go to my server's cPanel and go to the allowed IPs area and add `%`, after that connection was all successful.